# ViewModel != Domain Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model, viewmodel

While going through the best practices in mvc i found that DomainModel!=ViewModel

so if i have a requirement to show all employee details like name,age,address.
And I have a EmployeeModel class ie domain class, which has property like Id,Name,Age,Addresss,Department. In my view i need to show only Name,Age,Address, so do i create a view specific EmployeeViewModel with prop like Name,Age,Address and map it to EmployeeModel with automapper or something in controller?
Or Can I reuse my Existing EmployeeModel inside my EmployeeViewModel
i.e creating a EmployeeModel property inside EmployeeViewModel ?
What will be the best practice ?

```
public class EmployeeModel
{ 
 public int EmployeeId {get ; set} 

public string Name{get ; set}

public string Age{get ; set}

public string Department{get ; set}

}
```

So will i create a ViewModel Like this ?

```
public class EmployeeViewModel
{  

public string Name{get ; set}

public string Age{get ; set}

public string Department{get ; set}

}
```

OR Will I create a viewmodel like this ?

```
  public class EmployeeViewModel
    {  

     public EmployeeModel employeeModel {get; set;}

    }
```

Thanks

Comment: viewmodel is good to use where we want to merge two or more models or when model is complex .. in your case you can only create a simple model...

Comment: hi, this example is just for illustration, my view will go complex. Thats why i posted this ?

Comment: then 3rd case is best...

Comment: I was thinking like 2nd case will be best. I need only 3 properties in my view (Name,Age,Department) if we go by above example. So if we go by 3rd case , you are directly exposing model with 4 properties to your view right ? So we might be indirectly mixing our viewmodel with model ??

Comment: Better to keep a clean `ViewModel` with just your properties. That way you keep your `model` clean and add your Validation Rules in your `ViewModel`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your view will be complex, create the view model separate from your domain/ entity model.

Don't be tempted to encapsulate your domain model in your view model; the ups I sent on having a view model is that binding and logic encapsulation for your view is trivial, and tailored towards your view. The minute you include your domain model things get complex.

Oh, and look-up automapper. That will take away some (not all) of the mapping pain.

Comment: Thanks for that. Even I thought so. But most of the time people question this saying "reuse". ! We are having two similar classes having almost same set of properties. Then why don't we reuse the Model class in ViewModel instead of having different ViewModel class.How do i justify that ?

Answer (score 0):

I would go with properties in ViewModel. It keeps your model cleaner. You can handle your validation in your ViewModel instead. It also keeps your ViewModel cleaner from unnecessary properties and relations (in some cases).

```
public class EmployeeViewModel
{  

[Requried]
public string Name{get ; set}

public string Age{get ; set}

public string Department{get ; set}

}
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Even I thought so. But most of the time people question this saying "reuse". ! We are having two similar classes having almost same set of properties. Then why don't we reuse the Model class in ViewModel instead of having different ViewModel class.How do i justify that ?

Comment: @MichaelKovattil Well that's the lazy and easy way of doing things. Not so good for when your project scale. Your ViewModel represent the properties you use in your view. You are more flexible with using properties and not to mention controlling the validation better that way. You keep your Model clean of validation attributes. Use the same model in two ViewModels, and in one ViewModel you need to validate some properties but not in the other. Now trying to validate your model is not gone pass for one of the views. How do you solve a situation that? This is just one benefit.

Comment: @MichaelKovattil You get one of the benefits? Clean and validation. You can use something like AutoMapper to fill the Model from the ViewModel or the other way around if you think that is to much work.